# Linux thinks my 500GB hard drive is only 7.9GB

Tags: debian, hard-disk

Problem: I have a 500GB hard drive, which Linux currently believes is only 7.9GB. Specifically, Linux thinks it's 16514064 sectors, which is the old CHS limit, so I assume something somewhere has decided the drive doesn't support LBA, although I have no idea why given the drive used to work fine, and I have another 500GB drive of the exact same model in the same machine which is working.

`lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                                               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                  8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
└─md127                                              9:127  0 465.6G  0 raid1 
  ├─hddraid                                        253:10   0 465.6G  0 crypt 
  └─md127p1                                        259:5    0 265.9G  0 part  
sdb                                                  8:16   0   7.9G  0 disk  
...other drives
```

`sudo dmesg | grep 'sd[ab]'`:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep 'sd[ab]'
[   25.677445] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[   25.677459] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Drive-managed SMR disk
[   25.677461] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   25.677464] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 16514064 512-byte logical blocks: (8.46 GB/7.87 GiB)
[   25.677465] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[   25.677479] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   25.677481] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[   25.677485] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   25.677503] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   25.810898] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   27.303158] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[   27.340355] md: sdb does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
```

`sudo hdparm -N /dev/sda /dev/sdb`:

```
$ sudo hdparm -N /dev/sda /dev/sdb

/dev/sda:
 max sectors   = 976773168/976773168, HPA is disabled

/dev/sdb:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 max sectors   = 1610577834/1(1?), HPA setting seems invalid (buggy kernel device driver?)
```

`sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda /dev/sdb`:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda /dev/sdb

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050                      
        Serial Number:      53VACGYLT
        Firmware Revision:  AM003M  
        Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6
Standards:
        Supported: 8 7 6 5 
        Likely used: 8
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors:   976773168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:      476940 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:      500107 MBytes (500 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = 8192 KBytes
        Form Factor: 2.5 inch
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
        Advanced power management level: 127
        DMA: sdma0 sdma1 sdma2 mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 *udma5 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Advanced Power Management feature set
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
           *    64-bit World wide name
           *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Host-initiated interface power management
           *    Phy event counters
           *    Idle-Unload when NCQ is active
           *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
                Device-initiated interface power management
           *    Software settings preservation
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
                frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        110min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 110min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 50000394c378ce7b
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 000039
        Unique ID       : 4c378ce7b
Checksum: correct

/dev/sdb:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       @��A�T+QAJEJS       G� A    q"s�t�2Q.T�5" s 
        Serial Number:      53VFWB9TT
        Firmware Revision:  AJp"1�`�
        Media Serial Num:   ����������������������������������������
        Media Manufacturer: ��������������������
Standards:
        Used: unknown (minor revision code 0xf5ab) 
        Supported: 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 5 
        Likely used: 14
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   0
        heads           16      0
        sectors/track   63      0
        --
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:        8063 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:        8455 MBytes (8 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = 8192 KBytes
        Form Factor: 2.5 inch
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
Capabilities:
        IORDY(may be)(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 234 Current = 2
        Advanced power management level: 127
        Recommended acoustic management value: 125, current value: 170
        DMA: sdma0 sdma1 sdma2 mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 (?)
             Cycle time: min=32699ns recommended=32682ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 pio5 pio6 pio7 pio8 
             Cycle time: no flow control=62907ns  IORDY flow control=24058ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    SERVICE interrupt
           *    DEVICE_RESET command
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
                WRITE_VERIFY command
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
                READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    Advanced Power Management feature set
                Removable Media Status Notification feature set
           *    Power-Up In Standby feature set
           *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
           *    Address Offset Reserved Area Boot
           *    SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART self-test
           *    Media Card Pass Through Command feature set
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
           *    WRITE_DMA_QUEUED_FUA_EXT
           *    64-bit World wide name
                URG for READ_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
           *    URG for WRITE_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
           *    Time Limited Commands (TLC) feature set
           *    Command Completion Time Limit (CCTL)
                (301220 msec for TLC completion timer)
           *    Disable Data Transfer After Error Detection
           *    Write-Read-Verify feature set
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Free-fall Control feature set
           *    unknown 119[7]
           *    unknown 119[8]
           *    unknown 119[9]
           *    unknown 119[10]
           *    unknown 119[12]
           *    unknown 76[0]
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
           *    unknown 76[5]
           *    unknown 76[7]
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Phy event counters
           *    Idle-Unload when NCQ is active
           *    NCQ priority information
           *    Host automatic Partial to Slumber transitions
           *    Device automatic Partial to Slumber transitions
                unknown 78[0]
           *    Non-Zero buffer offsets in DMA Setup FIS
                Device-initiated interface power management
           *    Asynchronous notification (eg. media change)
           *    unknown 78[7]
           *    Device Sleep (DEVSLP)
                unknown 78[9]
           *    unknown 78[10]
                unknown 78[11]
           *    unknown 78[12]
                unknown 78[13]
           *    unknown 78[14]
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Read/Write Long (AC1), obsolete
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
                unknown 206[6]
                unknown 206[7]
                unknown 206[8]
                unknown 206[9]
                unknown 206[10]
                unknown 206[11]
                unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
                unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
                unknown 206[14] (vendor specific)
                unknown 206[15] (vendor specific)
           *    reserved 69[1]
           *    Extended number of user addressable sectors 
           *    Device encrypts all user data
           *    Optional ATA device 28-bit commands
           *    IEEE 1667 authentication of transient storage devices
           *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
           *    SET MAX SETPASSWORD/UNLOCK DMA commands
           *    WRITE BUFFER DMA command
           *    DEVICE CONFIGURATION SET/IDENTIFY DMA commands
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
                frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        112min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 112min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 50000394c4b8c204
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 000039
        Unique ID       : 4c4b8c204
Checksum: correct
```

Context, which may or may not be important: I have two identical 500GB hard drives in a RAID 1 md array, using the raw devices. I set up the RAID array on Debian Buster, and used it successfully for a few years. I have since done a clean install of Debian Bullseye. I didn't use the RAID array for a while after the clean install of Debian Bullseye, and just came to use it for the first time since installing Debian Bullseye, and it won't assemble, unsurprisingly given one of the drives is the wrong size.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo hdparm -N /dev/sdb`?

Comment: Added output to the question. Thanks, that has revealed a difference between the drives I can try and investigate.

Comment: Also added the output of sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda /dev/sdb; the metadata of /dev/sdb is clearly corrupt, so I expect the drive is dying/dead and I should replace it. Even if it can be persuaded to work again, I don't think I would trust it!

Comment: And today, I shut down the server with the two drives in, plugged them into another computer, both seemed to be working, plugged them back into the server, and they still seem to be working. Hopefully they stay that way...!

Comment: Have you checked this disk for bad blocks?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see things like these:

```
/dev/sdb:
 SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 max sectors   = 1610577834/1(1?), HPA setting seems invalid (buggy kernel device driver?)
```

and:

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       @��A�T+QAJEJS       G� A    q"s�t�2Q.T�5" s 
    Serial Number:      53VFWB9TT
    Firmware Revision:  AJp"1�`�
    Media Serial Num:   ����������������������������������������
    Media Manufacturer: ��������������������
```

Ready yourself for hardware troubles.

Stating that you've unplugged and plugged in a different computer (Good way to eliminate a part, ie. your computer, but also a way to exasperate the problem if the faulty device is the one that makes other devices fails 'cause of shorts/etc.) and re-plugged into your own computer again and things seems to "work", is typical indications of bad connections/cables ie.

- cable faults
- loose plugs
- bend/straight cables not connecting and  connecting once straightened/bended
- etc.